# Python RegEX that gets each name of a function in a file

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Trying to implement a regex script that gets the name of each function and returns them to a text file. The returning to text file part I got, the part I need some pointers in I don't.

```
# I just want to extract "name_i_want"
def name_i_want(self):
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A regex for this could be:

```
(?<=def )(\w+)(?=\()
```

Working regex example:

http://regex101.com/r/qR3fE7